# Escaping a batch file echo that starts with a forward slash and question mark

Tags: batch-file, escaping, cmd, dos, echo

Bit of a tricky one.  How can I correctly escape the following in a batch file?

```
echo    /?   display this help text
```

This particular combination of characters is treated as an "ECHO /?" command:

```
C:\Batch>ECHO       /?    display this help text
Displays messages, or turns command-echoing on or off.

  ECHO [ON | OFF]
  ECHO [message]

Type ECHO without parameters to display the current echo setting.
```

It does not respond to caret (^) escaping, ie. I've tried ^/?  /^? and ^/^?.

NB: As a workaround, I found that inserting other characters in between is enough to bypass the ECHO command line processor, eg:

```
echo ...   /?   display this help text
```

Still, this is not ideal and I wondered if there was a way to acheive the desired output, namely with /? at the start of the echoed message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For escaping echo arguments, you can use the alternative syntax `echo.`:

```
echo./?
```

Comment: `echo.` always access the disk, and it fails with output like `echo.\..\mybat.bat` (if mybat.bat exists in the current directory)

Comment: And it fails, if a file in the current dir exists with the name `echo` (without extension), I spend some time to find the problem, as the error message is confusing

Comment: I don't actually know the full theory behind it -- `echo.` has been the standard way to print an empty line ever since DOS 1.0, I didn't realize that the current implementation is so strange. Have you tried it in Powershell?

Answer (score 6):

For escaping echo arguments exists many variants, like `echo.`, `echo:`, `echo=`
But only `echo(` seems to be secure against any appended text.

These one fails, if files exists like `echo`, `echo[`, `echo]` or `echo+`

```
echo.
echo[
echo]
echo+
```

These one fails, if a file in the current directory exists named my.bat

```
echo\..\my.bat
echo:\..\my.bat
echo.\..\my.bat
```

These one fails independet of a file

```
echo/?
echo,/?
echo;/?
```

Only the `echo(` seems to be always safe against any content

Comment: There's also `echo=`, which can be broken by `/?` too.

Comment: Where are these variants documented? Or why are they possible? This all looks like a bug.

Comment: @utapyngo cmd.exe is a random result of the twelve monkeys. There aren't documents, it's simply tests (many test)