# Edit flat file to have a specific number of characters on each line?

Tags: file, batch-file, addition, spaces, flat

I would like to create a batch file that converts every line in a flat file to e specific amount of characters (add spaces at the end of every row).

Example:
I have a text file called "text.txt", and it looks like this:

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
```

I would like to run a batch file on it and recieve the following (all lines are 7 characters long):

```
1......
22.....
333....
4444...
55555..
```

(I had to replace my spaces with dots to make it visible)

Is this possible, and how?

---

#### Update:

Cool, that works perfect.

Is it also possible to convert a blank line (just CRLF) to 7 spaces? When I run the above on a file with empty lines they are deleted.

Thanks!

EDIT: Just to clarify, this is the file:

```
1
22

333
22

1
4444
55555
```

And I want to recieve:

```
1......
22.....
.......
333....
22.....
.......
1......
4444...
55555..
```

Thanks again!

---

#### Update 2:

Andriys answer is getting me a few steps forward. I've got a few issues though. If I leave the # sign out, the output will be like this (still periods instead of spaces):

```
1.......
22......
ECHO is off.
333.....
22......
ECHO is off.
1.......
4444....
55555...
```

And if a line starts with a space it will be outputted as:

```
ECHO is off.
```

Powershell is unfortunately not an option...

This might be a better example,
text.txt:

```
This is
 the input
file 
     I

 want to convert
```

Of course now we have to make the records longer, let's say 20 char.

Comment: The echo-code of Andriy could be changed to `ECHO(%line:~0,7%`, than it works with empty lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FOR` loop does omit empty lines. This is by design. To work around that, you could use the following command:

```
FIND /N /V "" < sourcefile
```

It is considered that no line can match `""` (empty string), so simply `FIND "" < file` would produce empty output. But the `/V` option causes the inversion of the output: instead of the lines that *match* the search string, `FIND` is to output those that *do not* match it. So `FIND /V "" < file` essentially causes `FIND` to output *all* the lines of `file`. And `/N` causes every line to be prepended with the line number, like this:

```
[number]text
[number]text
…
```

Accordingly, empty lines will look just like this:

```
[number]
[number]
…
```

So, now we are able to iterate over all the lines. We only need to remove all the `[number]` parts, then use @Dave's idea of appending the spaces and cutting out the first 7 characters. Here's a full script:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "delims=" %%L IN ('FIND /N /V "" ^<text.txt') DO CALL :process "%%L"
GOTO :EOF

:process
SET "line=%~1"
SET "line=%line:*]=%       "
ECHO(%line:~0,7%#
```

(The `#` character is only added for visual indication.)

**UPDATE**

Added `(` just after `ECHO`. This solves the `ECHO is off` issue. Basically, you can use a number of different characters instead of `(`, like `.`, or `,` for instance. But, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514746/escaping-a-batch-file-echo-that-starts-with-a-forward-slash-and-question-mark/6526957#6526957), `(` seems most reliable.

**UPDATE 2**

Added the `"delims="` option to the `FOR` loop after `/F` to account for spaces in the text.

Comment: @Martin: My fault, should have remembered to account for that issue from the beginning. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. Works much better now. Still ignores everything after first space though. "11 1" becomes "11  "

Comment: @Martin: I've grown quite inattentive to details recently, I'm really sorry. Please have a look at the solution now.

Comment: Thank's! Don't worry about the details. The update provided exactly what I needed.
By the way, why does the line become 8 char when I say ECHO(%line:~0,7%?

Comment: @Martin: Have no idea. It's always 7 chars when I test it. Cannot even imagine why there could be 8. Unless you forgot to remove `#`, but I'm sure you didn't. Strange... :\

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way (I left a period at the end of the spaces in "SET strTemp=%1       ." for visibility, you can remove it:

```
@ECHO OFF

FOR /F %%a IN (text.txt) DO Call :FixString %%a
PAUSE
EXIT

:FixString
 SET strTemp=%1       .
 ECHO.%strTemp:~0,7% >> output.txt
 EXIT /b
```

/edit:

Is Powershell an option for you? It would be easier to handle the carriage returns there, like this:

```
Foreach ($strLine in Get-Content c:\temp\text.txt) 
{ 
 $strTemp = $strLine + "........"
 If ($strTemp.Length -lt 1) {
  Add-Content c:\temp\output.txt $strTemp
 } Else {
  Add-Content c:\temp\output.txt $strTemp.SubString(0,7)
 }
}
```

This Powershell script will also behave if there are spaces within each line, the .cmd script I gave you earlier will have trouble with them (you'd need to change the delims= parameter of the For command to handle them).

Comment: Thank's, I'd love to use the powershell script, but I believe it's not an option.