# bat - ECHO is off in the txt files

Tags: windows, batch-file, echo

```
:obje7
set gn=%random%
if /i %gn% lss 1 goto obje%go%
if /i %gn% gtr 5 goto obje%go%
set goal%gn%="test"
echo hi > goal%go%.txt
echo hi > g2.txt
goto go
```

that sets test in goal%random_number%, right?

```
(
echo %goal1%
echo %goal2%
echo %goal3%
echo %goal4%
echo %goal5%
) >> mcbingo.txt
```

and the result i get is:

```
 ECHO is off.
 test
 ECHO is off.
 test
 test
```

and all the :objeX are the same code, but changed X and the g2.txt is g1.txt for example.

anyone have any idea whats wrong?

Comment: The environment doesn't contain a goal1 and goal3 variable.  So the echo command is just plain "echo" without an argument.  This is the expected outcome when you use random.  Run the .bat files many times more to get more of the variables defined.

Comment: oh, okay i see the problem. can i somehow make something like this
if goal1=* goto objeX

Answer (score 7):

Some of your `goal` variables remain uninitialised. When you are outputting them, the uninitialised variables evaluate to empty strings, and the corresponding `echo` commands simply look like this:

```
echo
```

Without parameters, `echo` displays the status of echoing batch commands to the console (when `ON`, they are displayed, when `OFF`, which is more typical in batches, they aren't).

To avoid this behaviour and display empty strings instead, add delimiters between `echo`s and `%goal…%`s. There's a number of delimiters you can use in that position, but, as follows from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514746/escaping-a-batch-file-echo-that-starts-with-a-forward-slash-and-question-mark/6526957#6526957), `(` seems most appropriate:

```
(
echo(%goal1%
echo(%goal2%
echo(%goal3%
echo(%goal4%
echo(%goal5%
) >> mcbingo.txt
```