# Slow processing a for loop that utilizes findstr

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, performance

I've got a somewhat weird case, where a for-loop is incredibly slow when I use findstr as the string for DO.

Its worth mentioning that the file (`old-file.xml`) that I'm processing contains about 200 000 lines.

This part is blazing fast, but can be rendered slower if I remove `| find /c ":"`

```
rem find total number of lines in xml-file
findstr /n ^^ old-file.xml | find /c ":" > "temp-count.txt"
set /p lines=< "temp-count.txt"
```

The code which is slow looks like this and I can't use the pipe trick above. It seems like the slow part is the `for` itself, as i'm not seeing any progress in the title bar until after 10 min.

```
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
rem start replacing wrong dates with correct date
for /f "usebackq Tokens=1* Delims=:" %%i in (`"findstr /n ^^ old-file.xml"`) do (
    rem cache the value of each line in a variable
    set read-line=%%j
    set line=%%i
    rem restore delayed expansion
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem write progress in title bar
    title Processing line: !line!/%lines%
    rem remove trailing line number
    rem set read-line=!read-line:*:=!
    for /f "usebackq" %%i in ("%tmpfile%") do (
        rem replace all wrong dates with correct dates
        set read-line=!read-line:%%i=%correctdate%!
    )
    rem write results to new file
    echo(!read-line!>>"Updated-file.xml"
    rem end local
    endlocal
)
```

**EDIT:**

Further investigation showed me that using this single line that should display the current line number being looped takes about 10 minutes on my 8MB file of 200 000 lines. That's just for getting it to start displaying the lines.

```
for /f "usebackq Tokens=1* Delims=:" %%i in (`"findstr /n ^^ old-file.xml"`) do echo %%i
```

So it seems like `findstr` is writing screen output hidden for the user, but visible for the `for`-loop. How can I prevent that from happening while still getting the same results?

**EDIT 2: Solution**

The solution as proposed by [Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8300722/487650) and finally revised by me.

This is a snippet from a much bigger script. Wrong dates are retrieved in another loop. And total number of lines are also retrieved from another loop.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem this part is for snippet only, dates are generated from another loop in final script 
echo 2069-04-29 > dates-tmp.txt
echo 2069-04-30 >> dates-tmp.txt

findstr /n ^^ Super-Large-File.xml > out.tmp

set tmpfile=dates-tmp.txt
set correctdate=2011-11-25
set wrong-dates=
rem hardcoded total number of lines
set lines=186442
for /F %%i in (%tmpfile%) do (
    set wrong-dates=!wrong-dates! %%i
)
rem process each line in out.tmp and loop them through :ProcessLines
call :ProcessLines < out.tmp
rem when finished with above call for each line in out.tmp, goto exit
goto ProcessLinesEnd
:ProcessLines
for /L %%l in (1,1,%lines%) do (
    set /P read-line=
    rem write progress in title bar
    title Processing line: %%l/%lines%
    for %%i in (%wrong-dates%) do (
        rem replace all wrong dates with correct dates
        set read-line=!read-line:%%i=%correctdate%!
    )
    rem write results to new file
    echo(!read-line:*:=!>>"out2.tmp"
)
rem end here and continue below
goto :eof

:ProcessLinesEnd
echo this should not be printed until call has ended

:exit
exit /b
```

Comment: What filesize has your `old-file.xml`? You could try to add an `echo I'm alive` into your loop, to see if the `findstr` is the problem

Comment: `old-file.xml` contains 200 000 lines, and is about 8 MB in size. I'm having `title` inside the for-loop instead of `echo I'm Alive`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two points here:

1- The `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` command is executed *with every line of the file*. This means that about 200000 times the complete environment must be copied to a new local memory area. This may cause several problems.

2- I suggest you to start with the most basic part. How much time takes the findstr to execute? Run `findstr /n ^^ old-file.xml` alone and check this before trying to fix any other part. If this process is fast, then add a single step to it and test again until you discover the cause of the slow down. I suggest you not use pipes nor `for /f` over the execution of `findstr`, but over the file generated by a previous redirection.

**EDIT** *A faster solution*

There is another way to do this. You may pipe findstr output into a Batch subroutine, so the lines can be read with `SET /P` command. This method allows to process the lines entirely via delayed expansions and not via the command-line susbtitution of `FOR /F`, so the pair of `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and `endlocal` commands are no longer necessary. However, if you still want to display the line number it is necessary to calculate it again.

Also, it is faster to load the wrong dates in a variable instead of process the %tmpfile% with every line of the big file.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem load wrong dates from tmpfile
set wrong-dates=
for /F %%i in (%tmpfile%) do (
    set wrong-dates=!wrong-dates! %%i
)
echo creating findstr output, please wait...
findstr /n ^^ old-file.xml > findstr.txt
echo :EOF>> findstr.txt
rem start replacing wrong dates with correct date
call :ProcessLines < findstr.txt
goto :eof
```

.

```
:ProcessLines
set line=0
:read-next-line
set /P read-line=
rem check if the input file ends
if !read-line! == :EOF goto :eof
rem write progress in title bar
set /A line+=1
title Processing line: %line%/%lines%
for %%i in (%wrong-dates%) do (
    rem replace all wrong dates with correct dates
    set read-line=!read-line:%%i=%correctdate%!
)
rem write results to new file
echo(!read-line:*:=!>>"Updated-file.xml"
rem go back for next line
goto read-next-line
```

**SECOND EDIT** *An even faster modification*

Previous method may be slighlty speeded up if the loop is achieved via `for /L` command instead of via a `goto`.

```
:ProcessLines
for /L %%l in (1,1,%lines%) do (
    set /P read-line=
    rem write progress in title bar
    title Processing line: %%l/%lines%
    for %%i in (%wrong-dates%) do (
        rem replace all wrong dates with correct dates
        set read-line=!read-line:%%i=%correctdate%!
    )
    rem write results to new file
    echo(!read-line:*:=!>>"Updated-file.xml"
)
```

This modification also omit the :EOF comparison and the calculation of line number, so the time gain may be significative after repeated it 200000 times. If you use this method, don't forget to delete the `echo :EOF>> findstr.txt` line in first part.

Comment: 1. I was given that recommendation as a "trick" in a previous question in order to get empty lines and special characters. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7886228/487650

2. The `findstr /n ^^ old-file.xml` takes about 3-4 minutes. But if I redirect the standard output using `1>nul` it's a lot faster but leaves me with no way of handling the output. Could you provide any proof-of-concept code for your recommendation?

Comment: @Niklas: There is another way to process empty lines and special characters. See my edit for a faster solution.

Comment: The `set/p` is a good,fast and simpler solution, if you don't have whitespaces at the line endings, else you will lose them. And also `set/p` can only handle <CR/LF> line ends, it fails with single <LF>

Comment: Thanks! I've tried it with the even faster modification. Works like a charm! I've updated my question with the solution.

Comment: Please look at my solution edited above, the only thing that seems to be the problem is when the loop in :ProcessLines is finished it will continue to call the parts below it. Any tricks to prevent it?

Comment: Nvm, `GOTO :EOF` was the solution. Never ever used that before. :)

Comment: Oops! I shown an example that ends at that point. If you want to add additional code after :ProcessLines, insert an `exit /B` at that point (I think `exit /b` is clearer than `goto :eof` :-)

Comment: @jeb: `set /P` DO preserve ending whitespaces. Also, `findstr` output will always have <CR/LF> at line ends...

Comment: @Aacini: You are right, `set/p` doesn't removes trailing whitespaces, it removes trailing control characters like TAB, single CR or LF. A awesome description is at [How Set/p works](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2160&p=9778)

Comment: @Aacini where is the `%lines%` comming from in the second option?

Answer (score 3):

A FOR /F expression will always executed/read/evaluated complete before the inner loop starts.

You can try it with

```
(
  echo line1
  echo line2
) > myFile.txt
FOR /F "delims=" %%a in (myFile.txt) DO (
  echo %%a
  del myFile.txt 2> nul >nul
)
```

It will display

```
line1
line2
```

In your case the complete `('"findstr /n ^^ old-file.xml"')` will executed and cached before the loop can start

**EDIT: Added Solution**

I measured with a file ~20MB with 370.000 lines

```
type testFile.txt > nul
findstr /n ^^ testFile.txt > nul

for /F "delims=" %%a in (testFile.txt) do ( 
  rem Nothing 
)

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`"findstr /n ^^ testFile.txt"`) do ...

findstr /n ^^ testFile.txt > out.tmp

type_nul     ~10000ms
findstr_nul  ~30000ms
for_file     ~ 1600ms
for_findstr  cancled after 10 minutes
findstr_tmp  ~  500ms !!!
```

I would recommend to use a temporary file, it's extremly fast.

```
findstr /n ^^ myFile.txt > out.tmp
set lineNr=0
(
  for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("out.tmp") do (
    set /a lineNr+=1
    set "num_line=%%a"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "line=!num_line:*:=!"
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
  )
) > out2.tmp
```

Btw. Your for/F splitting can fail, if the original line begins with a colon
`for /f "usebackq Tokens=1* Delims=:"`

Sample: `:ThisIsALabel`
`:ThisIsALabel`
  Findstr /n prepends a line number
`17::ThisIsALabel`
  the `delims=:` will split the first token and handles all colons as only one seperator
`ThisIsALabel`

Comment: I didn't know that `FOR /F` was evaluated before the loop starts. Good to know. However, I'm not able to use `FOR /F "delims=" %%a in (myfile.txt)` as I will not be getting empty lines nor special characters. As you recommended me in an earlier post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7886228/487650

Comment: The splitting has so far never failed, I've got cases where colons occur and they are not filtered out. `for /f "Tokens=1* Delims=:" %i in (file.txt) do echo %j` %j in this case will be the token *. I will try some things with your suggestions though, seems to be a much quicker alternative. However, will I not have problems parsing special characters? e.g ü,å,ä,ö, carets, & and |. I'm also unable to filter out only the line-number using `set "line=!num_line::*=!"`

Comment: @Niklas: jeb made a small mistake, should be `set "line=!num_line:*:=!"` :-)

Comment: I still doesn't get the actual line number using that, I dont know if that was on purpose or if you have any idea how that can be substituted to be included? e.g linenumber=123, data=content after line number

Comment: I add a simple `set /a lineNr+=1`, it's easier than to exclude it from the line itself