# How to change the order of lines in a file using a batch script?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

A have a text file that contains the results of a dir

```
dir "%local%" /b /a:d /s >> FolderList.txt
```

But I want to iterate in a `For` loop going from the last to the first line.

Since I believe this cannot be done in the `For` command, how can I generate a new file containing the same lines but in a inverse order?

Comment: I think this is beyond the scope of built in batch commands.

Comment: Not really, I need an algorithm to be applied using known batch commands

Answer (score 3):

You can't using the `For` command. But you can reverse the order of the `dir` listing that created the text file, using `dir "%local%" /o-n /b /a:d /s >> FolderList.txt`; the `-` means "reversed".

Comment: And what should I do when the file was not generated through a "dir"?

Comment: Your question specifically said "A have a text file that contains the results of a dir". I answered the question you asked; if you want to change it after the fact, post a new question. :)

Comment: Plus, what to do if I a want the reverse order of a file that was generated without a "dir /o"?

Comment: @Ken White, The actual question in the title has no mention of DIR. It simply asks how to reverse the order of lines in a file. I agree the details of how a particular file was originally created is a bit misleading though.

Answer (score 3):

I like the general strategy of both of Aacini's original solutions, but as written they have problems (some trivial, some significant)

**Original Aacini solution 1 using temp file with SORT:**

- Corrupts lines containing exclamation point (!)
- Strips leading colon(s) (:) from each line
- temp file creation using >> not as efficient as >
- Uses default SORT maximum line length of 4096 bytes
- Line count unnecessarily capped at 1 million
- Doesn't actually provide the asked for solution (an actual file output)
- Leaves behind the temporary file

**Modified solution 1**

Here is a version that fixes the problems. The only practical limitation is a maximum line length of 8180 bytes (characters). I'm not sure how high FINDSTR can count, but this solution will handle up to 999 billion lines. *(I agree with Aacini, no one would ever want to wait for such a large file to finish using a batch solution)* The line limit can easily be adjusted.

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set file="%~1"
set revfile="%~1.rev"
set tempfile="%temp%\revfile%random%.txt"
(
  for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /n "^" %file%') do (
    set "ln=%%a"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for /f "delims=:" %%n in ("!ln!") do set "prefix=000000000000%%n"
    echo !prefix:~-12!!ln:*:=!
    endlocal
  )
)>%tempfile%
(
  for /f "delims=" %%a in ('sort /rec 8192 /r %tempfile%') do (
    set "ln=%%a"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo(!ln:~12!
    endlocal
  )
)>%revfile%
del %tempfile%
```

**Aacini modified solution 1**

Aacini dramatically improved the robustness and performance with a modified solution 1 using SET /P and multiple TEMP files. The SET /P solution eliminates the need for a looped SETLOCAL/ENDLOCAL toggle, but it does have a few limitations.

- Lines must be terminated by `<LF><CR>` (normal for Windows, but Unix style  is sometimes encountered in Windows world).
- Lines must be <= 1024 characters
- Control characters at end of line will be stripped.

**Modified solution 1 take 2**

If any of the above limitations are a problem, here is an adaptation of my 1st solution that uses multiple temp files. Like Aacinis modified solution, it performs linearly with file size. It is about 40% slower than Aacinis modified version.

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set file="%~1"
set revfile="%~1.rev"
set "tempfile=%temp%\revfile%random%.txt"
findstr /n "^" %file% >"%tempfile%.1"
(
  for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%tempfile%.1") do (
    set "ln=%%a"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for /f "delims=:" %%n in ("!ln!") do set "prefix=000000000000%%n"
    echo !prefix:~-12!!ln:*:=!
    endlocal
  )
)>"%tempfile%.2"
sort /rec 8192 /r "%tempfile%.2" >"%tempfile%.3"
(
  for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%tempfile%.3") do (
    set "ln=%%a"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo(!ln:~12!
    endlocal
  )
)>%revfile%
del "%tempfile%*"
```

**Original Aacini solution 2 using environment variables:**

- Corrupts lines containing exclamation point (!)
- Strips blank lines
- Doesn't actually provide the asked for solution (an actual file output)

**Modified solution 2**

Here is a version that fixes the problems. The only known limitations are

- A maximum line length between 8181 and 8190, depending on line number
- A maximum file size slightly under 64MB.

This ***was*** my favorite solution because the file output can probably be eliminated by processing the file in the variables directly, thus completely avoiding the creation of any temporary file. ***Edit*** But based on info provided by Aacini, I learned it has severe performance problems as the environment grows. The problem is worse than Aacini realized - Even a simple SET command suffers dramatically with large environment sizes. **I've posted a question regarding this phenomenon at DosTips.** http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2597 *(I originally posted on SO, but apparently the question is too open ended for this site)*

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set file="%~1"
set revfile="%~1.rev"
set num=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /n "^" %file%') do (
  set /a "num+=1"
  set "ln=%%a"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  for %%n in (!num!) do for /f "delims=" %%b in (""!ln:*:^=!"") do endlocal&set "ln%%n=%%~b"'
)
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
(
  for /l %%n in (!num! -1 1) do echo(!ln%%n!
)>%revfile%
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two relatively easy ways to sort a file in reversed order. The first one is a direct method over file contents: add line numbers to all lines, sort the file in reversed order, eliminate line numbers:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Insert line numbers in all lines
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n ^^ %1') do (
    set /A lineNo=1000000+%%a
    echo !lineNo!:%%b>> tempfile.txt
)
rem Sort the file and show the result
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('sort /r tempfile.txt') do (
    echo Line %%a is %%b
)
```

The other method consist in load the file lines in a Batch array, that may be processed in any way you wish:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Load file lines in a Batch array
set lineNo=0
for /F "delims=" %%a in (%1) do (
    set /A lineNo+=1
    set "line[!lineNo!]=%%a"
)
rem Process array elements in reversed order:
for /L %%i in (%lineNo%,-1,1) do (
    echo Line %%i is !line[%%i]!
)
```

This last method works only if the size of the file is below 64 MB, because this is the limit for Batch variables.

Both methods can be modified to correctly process special characters (> < |).

**HOWEVER**

If you want to delete *all* the tree contents of a folder in bottom-up order, the "right" way to do that is via a recursive subroutine...

**EDIT** *Answer to dbenham*

As I wrote in my answer, the two methods I proposed can be modified to correctly process special characters and blank lines. In my answer I showed a *general method* to "change the order of lines" in reversed order paying no special attention on *create an output file* because the OP said in his own answer that "The objective was to reorder a list of folders to prevent problems while deleting them in sequence", so I thought that was enough to show him how to *process* the folders in reversed order. I also assumed that the list of folders:

- Have not exclamation points (!).
- Have not leading colons (:).
- Folder names are shorter than 4096 bytes.
- Have less than 1000000 lines.
- Have not blank lines.

I even thought (and still think) that the method the OP want to use to delete a list of folders is not adequate, and I mentioned this point under a big **HOWEVER** in my answer proposing to use a recursive subroutine instead.

**However** it seems that dbenham thought that the original question was something similar to "What is the most efficient method to sort a large file in reversed order?" and criticize my methods because they lack of such features. For this reason, I should reply in terms of this new question (efficient method), right?

In first place, it's funny to me that dbenham critizice my methods because "Doesn't actually provide the asked for solution (an actual file output)", but in his own Modified solution 2 he wrote that "This is my favorite solution because the file output can probably be eliminated by processing the file in the variables directly, thus completely avoiding the creation of any temporary file". ???

The two methods proposed by dbenham have a serious problem in terms of efficiency that was already discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293480/slow-processing-a-for-loop-that-utilizes-findstr/): the pair of `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and `endlocal` commands are executed *with every line of the file*. If the file is large (i.e. 200 000 lines and about 8 MB, as in the previous mentioned question) the environment will be copied to a new memory area and then deleted, and this will be repeated for 200000 times! Of course, this task is time-consuming. This problem becomes worse in dbenham's Modified solution 2: as the processing of lines go on, the environment grow as it store the file contents at that point. In the last lines of the file an environment almost equal to the size of the whole file will be copied to a new memory area *for every remaining line of the file*. Of course, this is the worst way to achieve this process in terms of efficiency!

There is another way to process empty lines and special characters that don't require the `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion - endlocal` pair. For details on this method and further discussion on efficient ways to process large files, see the previously mentioned question.

The following Batch files are my modified versions on "How to sort a large file in reversed order in an efficient way".

**Modified solution 1: using temp file with SORT**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set revfile="%~1.rev"
set tempfile=%temp%\revfile%random%

rem Insert line numbers in all lines
findstr /n ^^ %1 > "%tempfile%1.txt"
find /c ":" < "%tempfile%1.txt" > "%tempfile%2.txt"
set /P lines=< "%tempfile%2.txt"
call :JustifyLineNumbers < "%tempfile%1.txt" > "%tempfile%2.txt"
del "%tempfile%1.txt"

rem Sort the file in reversed order
sort /rec 8192 /r "%tempfile%2.txt" /o "%tempfile%3.txt"
del "%tempfile%2.txt"

rem Remove line numbers
call :RemoveLineNumbers < "%tempfile%3.txt" > %revfile%
del "%tempfile%3.txt"
goto :EOF

:JustifyLineNumbers
for /L %%i in (1,1,%lines%) do (
    set /A lineNo=1000000000+%%i
    set /P line=
    echo !lineNo!!line:*:=!
)
exit /B

:RemoveLineNumbers
for /L %%i in (1,1,%lines%) do (
    set /P line=
    echo !line:~10!
)
exit /B
```

This solution still have a limit of "only" 1147483647 lines (the maximum 32-bits signed positive integer minus the initial seed). Although this limit can be easily increased in the way suggested by dbenham, that modification imply a slower execution speed. The conclusion is: if you *really* want to reverse-sort a *very* large file don't use a Batch file, but a more efficient programming language (like C).

**Modified solution 2: using a Batch variable array**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set revfile="%~1.rev"
set tempfile=%temp%\revfile%random%

rem Load file lines in a Batch array
findstr /n ^^ %1 > "%tempfile%1.txt"
find /c ":" < "%tempfile%1.txt" > "%tempfile%2.txt"
set /P lines=< "%tempfile%2.txt"
del "%tempfile%2.txt"
call :CreateArray < "%tempfile%1.txt"
del "%tempfile%1.txt"

rem Process array elements in reversed order:
(for /L %%i in (%lines%,-1,1) do echo=!ln%%i!) > %revfile%
goto :EOF

:CreateArray
for /L %%i in (1,1,%lines%) do (
    set /P line=
    set ln%%i=!line:*:=!
)
exit /B
```

**EDIT** A *possible* solution for large environment problem.

I devised an idea that may solve, at least in part, the performance problems of SET command caused by a very large environment. Let's suppose that the internal operation of `SET VAR=VALUE` command follow these steps:

- When a new variable is defined with a value that exceed the current environment size, the environment is copied to a new area if the area beyond it is not available.
- The new area is just large enough to receive the new variable. No additional space is reserved.
- *The important one*: When a large variable is deleted, the remaining free space is **NOT** released. The environment memory block is never shrunk.

If previous steps are true, then the performance problems may decrease if we first reserve the desired environment space via large (8 KB) variables with the same name of the working variables. For example, to reserve 1024 KB we define 128 large variables; I suppose that the time required to define these 128 variables will be less than the time required to fill the same 1024 KB with shorter variables.

When the process is running, the definition of the first 128 working variables will take the time necessary to delete an 8 KB variable and define a shorter one, but for the variable 129 on the process must be faster because it just define a new variable in an already available space. To aid to this process, the variables must have names that place them at the end of the environment as dbenham indicated.

```
:ReserveEnvSpace sizeInKB
rem Define the first large variable (reserving 6 bytes for variable name)
rem (this method may be done in larger chunks until achieve the fastest one)
set z1=X
for /L %%i in (1,1,8184) do set z1=!z1!X
rem Define the rest of large variables
set /A lastVar=%1 / 8
for /L %%i in (2,1,%lastVar%) do set z%%i=!z1!
exit /B
```

You may use `MEM /P` command to check the size and placement of the environment memory block. In old MS-DOS (command.com) days the environment was placed after command.com, but if a resident program was placed after the environment, then it can't grow anymore. For this reason, the /E:nnnnn switch was provided in command.com to reserve a certain size in bytes for the environment.

I have no time to check this method for the rest of the day, but here it is for you!

Comment: +1 for 1st solution, though linenum seed could be 1 billion instead of 1 million. Many problems with 2nd solution - all fixable: blank lines stripped, lines starting with ; stripped, only first token of each line preserved. Also 64KB batch variable limit not correct. I believe limit is ~8k per variable for XP and beyond, but not sure about limit of total environment space. It is definitely more than 64KB.

Comment: @dbenham: Ops! I fixed a couple small obvious errors. I got these statements: "The maximum individual environment variable size is 8192bytes." and "The maximum total environment variable size for all variables, which includes variable names and the equal sign, is 65,536KB." from [this site](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx) under "Setting environment variables" heading.

Comment: Your quote in comment is obviously correct, but doesn't match answer (KB vs MB). 2nd solution still strips blank lines. I just realized both solutions will corrupt output if it contains !

Comment: Also, 1st solution strips leading colons (:) from each line

Comment: @dbenham: Re-ops! I fixed the error about max. environment size (it is 64 MB). I also replied to your proposed modified solutions...

Comment: Good info in link: set/end local analysis + advantage of temp files. Sorry - I got a bit lazy with my choice of language. I agree some of the "problems" I listed are minor points, though others may be important depending on situation. I agree the max line count "problem" is silly for performance reasons. Your modified soltn 1 is good as long as max line length<=1024, Windows style &lt;CR>&lt;LF> newlines used, and no cntrl chars at end of line. Could still be improved - no need for FINDSTR temp file since FOR /L has line nums.  Mod soltn 2 better but still bad performer: see my updated answer.

Comment: @dbenham: Please, read my last edit about a *possible* solution for the large environment performance problems.

Comment: Interesting idea, but I don't think it works: It takes nearly as long to clear a value as it does to set, and I see the env size shrink upon clear. This is getting off topic. I encourage you to participate in DosTips topic http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2597. I tried the question on SO, but a super user objected that it was too open ended.

Answer (score 0):

The objective was to reorder a list of folders to prevent problems while deleting them in sequence.

I came up with the following algorithm. I accept suggestions to make it more efficient or better.

```
@ECHO off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:: File that contains a list of folders
set file_from=%~1

:: Destination file, that will contain the sorted list
if "%2"=="" (
    set replace=1
    set file_to=_%file_from%
) else (
    set file_to=%~2
)
:: Create empty destination file
if exist "%file_to%" del "%file_to%"
copy NUL "%file_to%"

:: Temporary file
if exist ".\~Remaining.txt" del ".\~Remaining.txt"
copy "%file_from%" .\~Remaining.txt

:: Sort the order of folders

:while
set untouched=1
For /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (.\~Remaining.txt) Do (
    :: check if line was already added
    FindSTR /X /C:%%a "%file_to%"
    if errorlevel 1 (
        set untouched=0
        :: check if folder contains sub-folders to be added
        FindSTR /B /C:%%a\ .\~Remaining.txt
        if errorlevel 1 (
            :: remove current line from "~Remaining.txt"
            FindSTR /V /B /E /C:%%a .\~Remaining.txt> .\~Remaining_new.txt
            move .\~Remaining_new.txt .\~Remaining.txt
            :: add current line to destination file
            >> "%file_to%" ECHO %%a
            goto while
        )
    )
)
if untouched LSS 1 (
    goto while
)

if exist .\~Remaining.txt del .\~Remaining.txt

if defined replace (
    ECHO REPLACE!
    :: destination was not provided, so replace
    if exist "%file_from%" del "%file_from%"
    move "%file_to%" "%file_from%"
)
```

Comment: Apparently, the nesting of the FINDSTR doesn't work when %%a assumes values that contain spaces (eg.: a complete path such as "C:\Program Files")

Answer (score 0):

This code will reverse a text file, but with a few limitations.  Blank lines are omitted and lines containing special charaters cause it to fail: & < > |

```
@Echo Off
If "%1"=="" Goto Syntax
If "%2"=="" Goto Syntax
If Not Exist %1 (
    Echo File not found: %1
    Exit /B 2
)
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set SOF=~StartOfFile~
Set InFile=%~snx1~in
Set OutFile=%2
Set TempFile=%~snx1~temp
If Exist %OutFile%  Del %OutFile%
If Exist %TempFile% Del %TempFile%
Copy %1 %InFile% >nul
:Loop
Set "Line=%SOF%"
For /F "tokens=*" %%a In (%InFile%) Do (
    If Not "!Line!"=="%SOF%" Echo !Line!>>%TempFile%
    Set "Line=%%a"
)
Echo %Line%>>%OutFile%
Del %InFile%
If Not Exist %TempFile% (
    EndLocal
    Exit /B 0
)
Rename %TempFile% %InFile%
Goto Loop

:Syntax
Echo Usage:
Echo %~n0 input-file output-file
Echo.
Exit /B 1
```