# Get batch file name from a subroutine

Tags: batch-file, cmd, subroutine

In a subroutine, %0 expands to the subroutine name, not the script name. Is there a ligitimate way to still access the script name, or should I pass it as an argument?

```
@echo off

call :subroutine %~f0 my parameters
exit /b

:subroutine
shift
echo Script name is %0
echo Parameters: %1 %2
exit /b
```

I want the call statement to be just

```
call :subroutine my parameters
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a function you need to add at least one modifier to `%~0`.

```
call :test
exit /b

:test
echo 0   %0    - shows "test"
echo ~0  %~0   - shows "test"
echo ~f0 %~f0  - shows the batch name (full path)
exit /b
```

Comment: Thank you. I have already noticed this after reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559789/printing-a-paragraph-in-windows-batch.

Answer (score 2):

I believe %~nx0 will give you filename with extension and %~n0 will give you just the file name...

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using this at the top of my scripts:

```
set "This=%~dpnx0"
```

This way you still keep the full path of the currently running script. If there's the need to get just the name of the script you can use a FOR /F loop to extract it:

```
set "This=%~dpnx0"
echo This=%This%
for /F %%I in ('echo.%This%') do set "Name=%%~nxI"
echo Name=!Name!
```

Comment: I used to think that global variables are bad. But it looks like this is not the case.

Comment: @utapyngo: This is basically true but since there is no way to define constant values in Windows batch scripting I think that this is an acceptable exception. :)

Comment: Well, I guess you could just do `set "Name=%~nx0"` at the beginning. :) At the very least, your loop seems a bit overkill, you could have a simpler one: `for %%I in ("%This%") do set "Name=%%~nxI"`.