# How to add following string to batch file?

Tags: batch-file

How do I add following string to batch file for add it to a file?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.dev
    DocumentRoot "J:\repo\mydomain"
    ServerName mydomain.dev
    ErrorLog "logs/mydomain.dev-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/mydomain.dev-access.log" common
    <Directory "J:\repo\mydomain">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve

```
@echo off
set /p DomName=Enter Domain Name: 
Echo "<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.dev
        DocumentRoot "J:\repo\mydomain"
        ServerName mydomain.dev
        ErrorLog "logs/mydomain.dev-error.log"
        CustomLog "logs/mydomain.dev-access.log" common
        <Directory "J:\repo\mydomain">
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>" >> "J:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf"
:End
```

I want to replace "DomName" variable inside the string.

Thank you!!!

Comment: You might try the technique suggested in this question: [printing a paragraph in windows batch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559789/printing-a-paragraph-in-windows-batch)

Comment: what other tools or programing lanaguage do you have ? are you able to use cscript powershell or others?

Comment: I'm a php dev and no big idea about batch scripts. But its a pain for me when I need to create vhost every-time. I tired to automate that/

Comment: then you can do this too with PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `Echo` each line individually.

Simply use `%domname%` where you want to substitute the inputted text.

If you use the syntax

```
(
 echo something
 echo something else
)>somefilename
```

then a new file will be created containing the text that would have been `echo`ed. If you want to `append` to anexisting file, use `>>` in place of `>`

You need to `"escape"` some characters which have special meaning to batch. If you want a literal <kbd>></kbd> you need to code `^>` if you want the literal text to be produced. Same comment for <kbd><</kbd>